# Do any non-transitive (in a mathematical sense) slang terms exist?

Tags: slang

Are there any words that are slang for another word which is itself a slang term for something else, but the secondary slang term is not slang for the original word?

That is, given words `Y` and `Z`, where `Y` is a slang term for `Z`, does there exist a word `X` such that it is slang for `Y`, but not for `Z`?

Comment: May I suggest a clarification of the title?  e.g., _Do any non-transitive (in a mathematical sense) slang terms exist?_

Comment: As to the original question, I haven't thought of one yet, but I suspect that a good answer will be found somewhere in the slang for drugs and/or drug paraphernalia.

Comment: This question makes my head hurt.

Answer (score 15):

*Wiener* and *frank* are slang terms for a hot dog.  A "hot dog" is a slang term for a show-off.  Neither *wiener* nor *frank* is a slang term for a show-off.

Comment: wrt *Wiener*, *Frank*, and *hot dog*, how do you know which are slang terms and which is the correct word?

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Well, it doesn't really matter.  But just for the sake of argument, say "hot dog" is slang for *wiener*; *wiener* is slang for a whiny, wimpy person, and "hot dog" is not.

Answer (score 8):

"Lift" is slang for "ride" ("Give me a lift to the airport.") and "ride" is slang for "automobile" ("That's one sweet ride you're driving.") but "lift" certainly does not mean "automobile".

Answer (score 6):

It's arguable that what you ask for is impossible, slang or not.
Any example would have to involve a word with multiple meanings.
Strictly interpreted "is synonymous with" is an equivalence relation, therefore by definition transitive.
So if you say:

> A wanker is a tosser.
>   A tosser is a thrower.
>   But a wanker isn't a thrower.

You are relying on the [polysemy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polysemy) of "tosser".
It has two separate meanings: masturbator and thrower.
See also  [the fallacy of equivocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivocation#Fallacious_reasoning).

Comment: Ooops, I just wanted to answer with the link to the same [equivocation fallacious reasoning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivocation#Fallacious_reasoning) without reading answers but it happened to be the last words before "Your Answer" text area

Comment: I disagree. Mostly because 'is synonomous with' is not an equivalence relation, synonyms are like friends, a synonym of a synonym is not necessarily a synonym of the first; just follow a path through Roget's: truth->precision->rigor - truth and rigor are not in the same synonym set. Also, many words exhibit polysemy (like the 'hot dog' example) and that can allow great intransitivity.